# Unable to check consumer group on Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-zookeeper, producer-consumer

I have created the topic on 3 node kafka cluster as below

`/opt/UMB/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper broker1:2181,broker2:2181,broker3:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 64 --topic tmp1`

while checking the consumer groups i get the following error

`sudo /opt/UMB/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list`

```
[2022-04-10 14:06:49,256] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-04-10 14:06:49,358] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-04-10 14:06:49,460] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-04-10 14:06:49,675] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

I can successfully see the topic which i created

```
sudo /opt/UMB/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list
tmp1
```

I am also unable to check the lag and offset information (below command is working on older kafka version)

```
sudo /opt/UMB/kafka/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand --describe --group fas-ao-01 --zookeeper localhost:2181
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: zookeeper is not a recognized option
        at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleLongOptionToken(OptionParser.java:510)
        at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:56)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:396)
        at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupCommandOptions.<init>(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:1013)
        at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:49)
        at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala)
```

even if i change the **zookeeper** argument in above to **--bootstrap-server**, it throws below error

```
Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:260)
        at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService$$anonfun$describeConsumerGroups$1.apply(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:496)
        at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService$$anonfun$describeConsumerGroups$1.apply(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:495)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.describeConsumerGroups(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:495)
        at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.collectGroupsOffsets(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:511)
        at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.describeGroups(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:319)
        at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:66)
        at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
```

kafka version info is below

```
sudo /opt/UMB/kafka/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand --version
2.4.0 (Commit:77a89fcf8d7fa018)
```

Comment: Check if you are giving the right broker IP, see if you are able to `telnet` to the broker ip and port.

Comment: yes, i am able to telnet to the broker ip and port.

Comment: Check if you are `advertised.listeners` broker config is proper and that you are using the same ip:port to access it.

Comment: By the way, ideally Zookeeper should run on separate servers than Kafka

Comment: @JavaTechnical advertised.listeners is set as PLAINTEXT://<broker ip>:9092
what else do i need to check.?

Comment: i created the consumer groups, now i can see GROUP           TOPIC            PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID

the only thing which is missing is Consumer ID HOST CLIENT ID. what does it mean ?